# passport-oauth2 authorizationURL & TokenURL implementation

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using **passport-oauth2** for Oauth2 and confused in the implementation of authorizationURL & TokenURL as there is not any information present about this in official documentation.

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: any help, did you find it?